# I need to apply the Savings heuristic and Nearest Neighbor to a set of VRP (Vehicle routing problems), quickly

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, vehicle-routing, optaweb-vehicle-routing

My knowledge of programming isn't zero but also it isn't much more than that. I need to run a set of 9 Vehicle routing problems specifically with those heuristics.

I tried running VeRyPy on Python 2.7 but I couldn't get to install every module it needed for a whole week, it worked to some point but would fail in specific problems. Then tried compiling VRPH, the VS2008 version didn't work properly and couldn't get to compile the VS2010 version.

There's gotta be a solution that doesn't require that amount of setup and would let me run my problem for once that I'm not finding. My time is running out and all I need is a tip.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Author of VeRyPy here. Sorry to hear about your issues with the VRP solver(s). I'm aware that installation should be streamlined, but as it goes with academic software, after I was done with my previous research, I've got very limited to work on the codebase and documentation of VeRyPy. However, if the need is still there, feel free to drop me an email with the details (your OS, environment, and any possible error messages) and I will try to help you get the Savings and NN heuristics running. Regarding comparison with, e.g., VRPH, The advantage of VeRyPy is that most of the algorithms therein can replicate The results from the literature. Hence, when you say that the results were produced with Clarke & Wright Savings heuristic, in a sense, they really were!